# Dynamic SQL Incorrect Syntax in the WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm getting an incorrect syntax near 'dtproperties'. It works perfectly fine if I don't have it as a dynamic sql. But why isn't it working if it's in a dynamic sql? My assignment requires  me to use the dynamic sql.

```
USE MyGuitarShop;
DECLARE @DynamicSQL varchar(8000);

SET @DynamicSQL =
 'SELECT TOP 1 sys.tables.name, COUNT(*) AS TotalTable
 FROM sys.tables
 WHERE sys.tables.name NOT IN ('dtproperties', 'sysdiagrams')
 GROUP BY sys.tables.name
 ORDER BY sys.tables.name';

EXEC (@DynamicSQL);
```

Comment: Does it count as dynamic SQL if it's not actually dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double the single quote to escape a single quote.

```
SET @DynamicSQL =
 'SELECT TOP 1 sys.tables.name, COUNT(*) AS TotalTable
 FROM sys.tables
 WHERE sys.tables.name NOT IN (''dtproperties'', ''sysdiagrams'')
 GROUP BY sys.tables.name
 ORDER BY sys.tables.name';
```